# Is there a reason sometimes the jQuery just doesn't work when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The following code works; however, my issue is that sometimes when the page is loaded in incognito, I have to load the page twice for the total cost to display the correct value.

When it fails, the cost displays 0.
**Desired outcome:** I need the correct amount to display each time someone loads the page.

```js
jQuery(".modal").delay(1000).fadeIn();
jQuery('#ip').delay(3000).fadeIn();
jQuery(".close").click(function() {
  jQuery(".modal").hide();
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.tos').on('scroll', chk_scroll);
});

// Check to See if User Scrolls to The Bottom of Terms of Service in Modal
function chk_scroll(e) {
  var elem = jQuery(e.currentTarget);
  if (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() == elem.outerHeight()) {
    console.log("bottom");
    jQuery('.continue-btn').fadeIn("slow");
  }
}

jQuery(".continue-btn").click(function() {
  var agree = true;
  jQuery(".modal").hide();
});


jQuery.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
  jQuery("#ip").html(response.ip);
  var ipaddress = response.ip;
  var countryid = response.country;
  var cityloc = response.city;

  jQuery("#city-value").html(response.city);
  jQuery("#country-value").html(response.country);
  //    jQuery("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));

  // Determine User's Country

  if (response.country == 'US') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("United States|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'CA') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Canada|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'AD') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Andorra|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'AT') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Austria|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'BH') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Bahrain|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'BE') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Belgium|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'CY') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Cyprus|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'DK') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Denmark|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'FI') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Finland|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'FR') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("France|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'DE') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Germany|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'IS') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Iceland|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'IE') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Ireland|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'IL') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Israel|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'JP') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Japan|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'KW') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Kuwait|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'LI') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Liechtenstein|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'LU') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Luxembourg|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'MC') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Monaco|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'NL') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Netherlands|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'NO') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Norway|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'OM') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Oman|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'QA') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Qatar|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'ES') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Spain|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'SE') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Sweden|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'CH') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Switzerland|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'GB') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("United Kingdom|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'BN') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Brunei|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'NZ') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("New Zealand|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'AE') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("United Arab Emirates|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'AU') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Australia|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'BB') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Barbados|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'HR') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Croatia|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'EE') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Estonia|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'GR') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Greece|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'IT') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Italy|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'HU') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Hungary|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'JO') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Jordan|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'KZ') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Kazakhstan|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'LV') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Latvia|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'LT') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Lithuania|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'MT') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Malta|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'PL') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Poland|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'PT') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Portugal|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'RO') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Romania|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'SA') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Saudi Arabia|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'SG') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Singapore|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'SK') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Slovakia|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'SI') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Slovenia|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'TW') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Taiwan|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'MY') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Malaysia|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'PH') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Philippines|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'CN') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("China|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'HK') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Hong Kong|245");
  } else if (response.country == 'ID') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Indonesia|245");
  }

  // Countries With Pricing of $200 
  else if (response.country == 'ZW') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Zimbabwe|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'ZM') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Zambia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'YE') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Yemen|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'VN') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Viet Nam|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'VE') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Venezuela|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'VU') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Vanuatu|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'UZ') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Uzbekistan|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'UG') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Uganda|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'TV') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Tuvalu|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'TZ') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Tanzania|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'TJ') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Tajikistan|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'SD') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Sudan|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'LK') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Sri Lanka|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'PK') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Pakistan|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'NG') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Nigeria|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'NE') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Niger|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'KE') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Kenya|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'JM') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Jamaica|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'IN') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("India|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'HN') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Honduras|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'HT') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Haiti|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'GT') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Guatemala|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'GH') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Ghana|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'GM') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Indonesia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'GA') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Indonesia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'FJ') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Indonesia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'ET') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Indonesia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'ER') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Indonesia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'GQ') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Indonesia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'SV') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Indonesia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'EG') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Indonesia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'DO') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Indonesia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'DM') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Indonesia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'DJ') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Indonesia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'CI') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Côte d'Ivoire|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'CG') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Indonesia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'KM') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Indonesia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'TD') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Indonesia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'CF') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Indonesia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'CM') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Indonesia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'KH') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Indonesia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'CV') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Cabo Verde");
  } else if (response.country == 'BI') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Burundi|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'BW') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Botswana|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'BY') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Belarus|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'BD') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Bangladesh|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'AW') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Aruba|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'AM') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Armenia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'DZ') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Algeria|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'UY') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Uruguay|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'UA') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Ukraine|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'PY') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Paraguay|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'NI') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Nicaragua|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'MA') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Morocco|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'EC') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Ecuador|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'BR') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Brazil|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'BZ') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Belize|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'AR') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Argentina|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'AL') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Albania|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'TH') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Thailand|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'IQ') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Iraq|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'BO') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Bolivia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'TR') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Turkey|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'PE') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Peru|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'KR') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("South Korea|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'ZA') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("South Africa|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'PA') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Panama|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'MX') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Mexico|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'CR') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Costa Rica|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'CO') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Colombia|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'CL') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Chile|200");
  } else if (response.country == 'BG') {
    jQuery("#input_1_15").val("Bulgaria|200");
  }

  // Redirect Other Countries to Sorry Page
  else {
    var url = "https://www.devopsinstitute.com/exam-unavailable/";
    jQuery(location).attr('href', url);
  }
}, "jsonp");

setTimeout(function() {
  var getValue = jQuery("input[name=input_7]").val();
  var errorUrl = "https://www.devopsinstitute.com/something-went-wrong/";

  // Show Exam Cost in Console

  console.log(getValue);

  // If Exame Cost is 0 Redirect User to Error Page
  if (getValue == "0") {
    jQuery("#gform_submit_button_1").css("display", "none");
    console.log("⚠️ ERROR: AMOUNT CANNOT BE 0 ⚠️");
    jQuery(location).attr('href', errorUrl);
  }
}, 7000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything that you want to run when the page first loads should be within a "ready" block, i.e.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  //your code here
});
```

That way, you guarantee that all the HTML elements and other content which it might rely on have already been loaded when the code begins to execute. It's far more reliable then just running the code directly in the main body of the JS, or trying to use timeouts to guess how long things might take to load.

You didn't identify whether you'd debugged and narrowed down this failure to any more specific area in the code or found any error messages, but if it's a startup / page load issue then it's often related to missing DOM elements etc. which the JS code then cannot interact with because the browser hasn't loaded them yet.

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

---

N.B. This is the same functionality as is provided by the ["DOMContentLoaded" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) in vanilla JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  //your code here
});
```

Comment: This made the page load quicker but the function still seems to not be working on occasion. Would it help if I sent you the url?

Comment: Not really no, that's now how stackoverflow works - you need to provide all the relevant info here in your question so it's preserved for future readers, not just providing a quick fix for you (with the problem no longer visible once your site is fixed). Have you tried debugging the script using your browser's Developer Tools so that we get a more precise description of the problem. "Not working" tells us pretty much nothing useful.